# How to find biggest number from numbers in string format

Tags: excel

I'm stuck at finding the biggest number from numbers in string format. I have a sheet with numbers in string format(text e.g '101) displayed from A4 to M4 with an empty cell in between and I want to find the biggest number from those. If I'm using =MAX(VALUE(A4:M4)) everytime I get the number in first the column (the number from A4 in my example).

Below is a link to a capture of my document (Green background represents the result is correct, red background represents the result is incorrect. Note that in green background I use INT values while in red background I use string (or text) values)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swbvf.jpg

Comment: Why are you using numbers in string format?

Comment: In the main project that I received, the numbers should be like 001, 002, and so on and that's why I'm using string format (I didn't mention it in the question since I'm working on a test right now)

Comment: That's what a number format is for. You can add leading zeros, changing the format of the number without converting it to text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to enter the formula as an array formula:

```
{=MAX(VALUE(A4:M4))}
```

(press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

Comment: Thank you cybernetic, that's exactly what I was looking for!